# how to handle click function on ion-toggle

Tags: angular, ionic2, ion-toggle

here is my .html file

```
<ion-item no-lines (click)="update()" >
        <ion-label> Notification</ion-label>
        <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="notify" ></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
```

the above code works when i click on the `Notification` text but when i click on the `ion-toggle` i am not able to invoke the function what should i do to invoke the function.

here is my .ts file

```
update(){
 console.log("invoking notification");
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you use `ngModel` it's best to use `ngModelChange`

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="notify" (ngModelChange)="update($event)" ></ion-toggle>
```

otherwise you can use

```
<ion-toggle (ionChange)="update($event)"></ion-toggle>
```

See also https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toggle/Toggle/

Comment: is there any other way i can use because ionchange method invokes two time. when ever my page appears i am setting my toggle to be true or false because of that i am automaticaly invoking the function but i want when the user manually choose that time only i shuodl invoke the function

Comment: What about `ngModelChange`? Does it also call twice? Otherwise you might need to ignore the first event. I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: Glad to hear :)